# Достать значение атрибута

Tags: python, xml, xmlparser, атрибуты, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть такой xml файл.

```
<content id="1" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26"> 
<decision date="2000-01-01" number="96-ÐÈ" org="Организация"/> 
</content>
```

Подскажите как можно получить значение "org" используя язык программирования python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, разобрался как. Может кому нужно будет.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *

XmlDocument = parse(u'C:\\dump.xml')

ContentElement = XmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("content")
DecisionElement = XmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("decision")

for element in DecisionElement:
    print element.getAttribute('org')
```